# SQL Server: Bring all data for all users

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have made one sp that checks whether a user is available or not. the sp calculates balance of users.

Now if user is selected from UI,it runs fine. but if it is not selected, then i need to bring the balance for all users in the application.

For that i have made cursor that brings up balance for all users. But my sp has many case-when and putting cursor inside that is not feasible solution.

Hence i made a function but threw an error of

**Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client.**

I am using SQL Server 2005. Please guide me.

**UPDATED: FUNCTION ADDED**

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fngetBalance()

RETURNS @balanceTable TABLE
(
    Parambalance bigint
)   
AS
BEGIN
--INSERT INTO @balanceTable (Parambalance) VALUES (1)

DECLARE getBalance CURSOR
FOR 
  SELECT  temp2.BillCharge - temp2.Receipt - temp2.AdjustedAmt AS Balance from
                    (SELECT SUM(Fees) AS BillCharge, temp.*  FROM BillDetail
                    JOIN
                    (SELECT
                            BillDetail.PatientID,
                            CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), dbo.Examination.ExamDt, 101) AS BillDate,
                           'Payment received' AS DescOfService,
                            Payment.BillID AS BillID, 
                            SUM(Isnull(Payment.PlanPaid, 0)) + SUM(IsNull(Payment.PatPaid, 0))  as Receipt,
                            SUM(ISNULL(Payment.WriteOff1, 0)) + SUM(IsNUll(Payment.Writeoff2, 0))  as AdjustedAmt
                           --Examination.ExamDt   
                          FROM
                            Billdetail
                            JOIN Payment ON Payment.BillDetailID = BillDetail.BillDetailID
                            JOIN dbo.Examination ON dbo.BillDetail.ExaminationID = dbo.Examination.ExaminationID 
                            GROUP BY Payment.BillID, Examination.ExamDt,BillDetail.PatientID) temp ON 
                            temp.BillID = Billdetail.BillID
                            GROUP BY temp.BillID, temp.Receipt, temp.AdjustedAmt,temp.BillDate, temp.DescOfService, temp.PatientID) AS temp2
                            ORDER BY temp2.PatientID
--SELECT temp-temp2  AS balance from
--(SELECT SUM (BillDetail.Fees) AS fees  FROM dbo.BillDetail GROUP BY billdetail.PatientID) AS temp
--JOIN
--(SELECT SUM (payment.planPaid) + SUM(payment.patpaid) + SUM (Payment.WriteOff1) + SUM (Payment.WriteOff2) AS payment
--FROM dbo.Payment GROUP BY payment.PatientID) temp2
OPEN getBalance 
FETCH NEXT FROM getBalance
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
FETCH NEXT FROM getBalance
END

CLOSE getBalance
DEALLOCATE getBalance
RETURN
END
```

Comment: Can you post what you have so far?

Comment: @mark: what you wish to have: sp or function or cursor. btw SP is way to bigggggg....

Comment: Show us what you have don in the function. This is where the error is coming from

Comment: @Xor power: It's too big to post? Then can you post a simplified version that gives the same error?

Comment: How are you trying to call this function? If your function returns a table you have to select against that function to generate a result set (see my answer below).

Comment: @brandon: the select comes at later stage. when i am creating the function, i am getting the error posted in question.

Comment: @Xor, I think you want to fetch next from getbalance into a variable. The fetches are generating result sets, which you can't do from within a table valued function. You need to store the balance in a variable and add that to the returned table if you want callers to have access to it.

Comment: @Brandon: I am not getting by what you mean..

Comment: @Xor, see BlueMonkMN's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert the results of your fetch statement into your return value table.

```
  CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fngetBalance()
  RETURNS @balanceTable TABLE
  (
     Parambalance bigint
  )
  AS
  BEGIN
     DECLARE getBalance CURSOR FOR
     SELECT [... insert your code here ...]

     DECLARE @balance bigint

     OPEN getBalance
     FETCH NEXT FROM getBalance
     INTO @balance
     WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
     BEGIN
       INSERT INTO @balanceTable VALUES(@balance)
       FETCH NEXT FROM getBalance
       INTO @balance
     END
     CLOSE getBalance
     DEALLOCATE getBalance
     RETURN   
  END
```

Comment: +1 for the example. I was referencing something like this in my comments, but an example is worth 1000 comments.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use a [table valued function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx).  You need to return the table from within the function.  Note: To generate a useable result set you need to call the function like so:

`select * from myFunction`

Hope that helps.

Comment: you are too close. i have created a table valued function. the same is attached